# Java Object Overwriten and not new made

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

for my next Java project I wanted to make a Vector (Vektor named) class for saving 1,2 or 3 dimensional Vectors on my own. The Class Vektor has three constructors for each number of parameters put in when created. It has a show() method as well to print aus the Vektor as an array. When initiating the Vektors there appears the following Problem:
Initiating code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Vektor x = new Vektor(1);
Vektor xy = new Vektor(2,3);
Vektor xyz = new Vektor(4,5,6);
x.show();
xy.show();
xyz.show();
```

The Output:

```
[4,5,6]
[4,5,6]
[4,5,6]
```

The class Vektor looks like this:

```
public static int[] alpha = new int[3];
public Vektor(int x) {
this.x = x;
alpha[0] = x;
}
public int[] show() {
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(alpha));
return alpha;
```

Of course the Constructor changes with the number of Parameters. Along with the Array alpha which stores all Variable in Vector, there are the Variables x,y,z which are filled with their values when appearing in the constructor.
I really hope somebody can help me get it stright why i get  3 times the same Output and not three different Outputs, as i created three different objects. Thx, Luca

UPDATE: The Problem was found. The array should not be classified as "static".
Thank you, all.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `alpha`. My guess is that it's static... (Hint: always show a [mcve], not just bits and pieces of your code.)

Comment: static variable is the same for every object. deleting "static" should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have provided, it seems that every time you instantiate the `Vektor` class, the `alpha` array gets updated to hold some (if not all) recent constructor arguments of the most recent instantiation.

You need to change the alpha array from static to public (ideally private with getters/setters) to encapsulate the `alpha` array within each object that creates it.